# Save Files to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have the table "tblTransDocs" with these fields (DocId(pk),TransId(pk),rev,...and for each row of this table i can have file. now my question is i have to make another table with these fields (fileId(int),file name (varchar) , content type (varchar) ,data (var binary) and adding Fileid as a foreign key to "tblTransDocs" or i can add columns to "tblTransDocs" for saving files to the database like (file name (varchar) , content type (varchar) ,data (var binary) .

which way is correct?

Comment: [To BLOB or Not To BLOB](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525)

Comment: @Oded - That doesn't cover `FILESTREAM` available in 2008.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Sure. But `FILESTREAM` just points to the... filesystem. Did you know you can change the contents of a file and SQL Server will not bat an eyelid?

Comment: actually my question is, i have to make separate table for files or i can add columns to my table that i have before.

Comment: If performance becomes a problem, then you can think about separating to another table (unless the requirements calls for a separate table).

Comment: But To FILESTREAM or not to FILESTREAM is still something to consider. It has quite a few implications

Comment: what i have seen in some sample use     "string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data)" +

           " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)"; now if my old table has some records and i want just filling new fields like  (file name (varchar) , content type (varchar) ,data (var binary) . what sql statement i have to use.? i mean uploading file after inserting record to table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the file in the table, you can add an **image** field to store the blob data.  Yes, you can add it to the existing table; you do not need to create a second table, that would be up to your design.  FILESTREAM is also an option, as mentioned.